# Проблема с кодом на ajax для отправки сообщения в мессенджер whatsapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input

Есть код, который должен отправлять сообщения в whatsapp

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// URL для запроса POST /message
var url = 'https://eu43.chat-api.com/instance**********/message?token=**********';
var data = {
    phone: '7**********', // Телефон получателя
    body:  'Здесь должно быть сообщение', // Сообщение
};
// Отправим запрос при нажатии на кнопку
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
$.ajax(url, {
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    type : 'POST'
});
});
});
```

После с помощью некоторых рук я его переделал для получения данных из input

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Отправить запрос при нажатии на кнопку
$(".button").click(function() {
$.ajax('https://eu43.chat-api.com/instance**********/message?token=**********', {
  data: JSON.stringify({
    phone: $('input[name="recipient"]').val(),
    body: 
    `Имя: ${$('input[name="name"]').val()}\n`.
    `Телефон: ${$('input[name="phone"]').val()}\n`.
    `Адрес: ${$('input[name="address"]').val()}\n`.
    `Заказ: Pizza "Margarita"`
  }),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'POST'
});
});
});
```

Но код не работает и даже событие в Network в консоли разработчика пропало, хотя раньше был ответ. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять синтаксис:
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "url"
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, простая ошибка

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Send a request when the button is clicked
$(".button").click(function() {
$.ajax('https://eu43.chat-api.com/instance**********/message?token=**********', {
  data: JSON.stringify({
    phone: $('input[name="recipient"]').val(),
    body: 
    `Name: ${$('input[name="name"]').val()}\n`+
    `Phone: ${$('input[name="phone"]').val()}\n`+
    `Address: ${$('input[name="address"]').val()}\n`+
    `Order: Pizza " Margarita"`
  }),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'POST'
});
});
});
```